Is it possible to configure a converter for spring's HttpInterface?
Let's say I'm given the below endpoint:
GET /hello/{id}?idType={idType}

where the allowed values of idType are ["loginId", "contactId"]
I have to consume this service using:
@HttpExchange("/hello")
public interface HelloClient {
    @GetExchange("/{id}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String id, @RequestParam IdType idType);
}

where IdType is an enum:
public enum IdType {
    LOGIN_ID("loginId"),
    CONTACT_ID("contactId");
    String idType;
    IdType(String idType) { this.idType = idType; }
}

normally one could define a Converter<IdType, String> bean I guess and spring would use that to do it's magic and send the correct request:
GET /hello/xyz?idType=loginId

How can I do the same with HttpInterfaces?
helloClient.hello("xyz", IdType.LOGIN_ID);
expected: GET /hello/xyz?idType=loginId
actual: GET /hello/xyz?idType=LOGIN_ID

I don't want to have this code:
helloClient.hello("xyz", IdType.LOGIN_ID.getIdType());

Is something like this possible? Converter doesn't seem to be used.

After defining the HTTP Interface we have to create a proxy of type RestClient, WebClient or RestTemplate. Yes we can register HttpMessageConverters either on only the proxy object we create or globally by registering it as a bean. This will let us add or modify the content in the body and headers from what I can see.
In our case now we want to modify the query parameters which cannot be done by the converters I think. So one approach I can think of is through adding an interceptor like I've added below when creating a RestClient proxy.
    @Bean
    public UtilityClient createClient () {
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
            .requestInterceptors(interceptorsConsumer -> {
                interceptorsConsumer.add(
                        (request, body, execution) -> {
                            String query = request.getURI().getQuery();
                            // our modification code here.
                            return execution.execute(request, body);
                        }
                );
            })
            .build();
        RestClientAdapter adapter = RestClientAdapter.create(restClient);
        HttpServiceProxyFactory factory = HttpServiceProxyFactory.builderFor(adapter).build();

        UtilityClient service = factory.createClient(UtilityClient.class);
        return service;
    }

And we can add the logic to modify the query parameters I guess in the interceptor. But I do feel it can be flaky and unpredictable to modify strings. Would love to see if anyone has any other approach to do this.
